# In NotePad++ how can I copy and paste everything inside a "+" section?

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++ you can collapse code blocks with the "+" button.... how can I collapse a large code block, copy it, then in a new file, collapse a large code block, and then replace the entire code block with the copied one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not do this in a one step. But here is a workaround for this. While in the shrink state (with + is in place) **Right click** immediately after the **+** and in the popup menu click **Begin/End Select**. Then **Right click** at the beginning of the next line again and click **Begin/End Select**. This will select the text between two positions. Now copy the content by pressing **Ctrl-C** and repeat the same procedure to select the text to be overwritten. Then press **Ctrl-V** to paste the text.
[image] [image] [image]