# Notepad++ Retain code Fold on Paste

Tags: copy, notepad++, paste, folding

I have a folded code block in Notepad++

[+] /begin{code}

I want to copy and paste this code block. However, when I do so, it is expanded out, like this:

/begin{code}

...

/end{code}

when I really want to retain the folded code and have it appear like this when I paste:

[+] /begin{code}

Is there any way to do this in Notepad++, or any other editor that supports this feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In NotePad++ how can I copy and paste everything inside a "+" section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536320/in-notepad-how-can-i-copy-and-paste-everything-inside-a-section)

Comment: @Toto It is not a duplicate because that question (although entirely unclear) seems to ask how to _retain_ text inside the collapsed section, whereas this question asks how to _exclude_ that text.